# position a div on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I want position a DIV with the content of an addsense script on top of a img that I use as a banner.

I have the img tag inside a div. then I put the google script inside a following div and set this style to it

```
style="float:right;left:250;z-index:2"
```

The add is shown below the img and not on top of it. Any ideas??

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You want to position the second div with `absolute`:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbNZu/

Relevant code:

```css
img {
    border: 2px solid black;   
}

#container {
    position: relative;    
}

#example {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px; 
    
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/193/129">
    <div id="example">This is my div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also added a z-index value of 2 and float:left to the div that contains the image

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `position: absolute;` and the parent must be `position: relative`. Without a proper position rule set z-index means squat.

Answer (score 2):

Have the parent with `position: relative`, the children with `position: absolute`, and use negative values for margin on the children to move it on top. You may not even need to deal with z-index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `position: relative`, and a negative value for `top`.