# Best solution for text ontop of image

Tags: html, css, position

I want to make the following element.
[image]

Basically an image in top of a page layout, and then a box on top of that image, containing a header and some more text.
But, what is the most optimal way of doing this in regards to responsiveness. I imagine something like the following markup

```
<div class="header">
<img src="myimage.png" alt="" />
<div class="text">
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And then set .header to position relative, img to max-width of 100%, and .text to position absolute, bottom: -50%, left: 10% etc.
But this does not scale well, and absolute position seems to me, to be a bit invalid in regards to responsiveness. Also, there is content below the element, that should move accordingly to the amount of text, in the text element. If if is positioned absolute, that gets more tricky to manage.

Any ideas to another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218204/position-a-div-on-top-of-an-image):

```css
img {
    border: 2px solid black;   
}

#container {
    position: relative;    
}

#example {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px; 
    
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://i34.tinypic.com/4tlkci.jpg">
    <div id="example">This is my div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Bob. Yeah, i know thats the default way of doing it - same as my example. But, it does not work well in reponsive situations and in regards to content below the container, when the example div, contains alot of text.

Comment: you will have to use media queries to make it responsive on other devices

Comment: @XenioGracias Yep, but still does not solve the problem with the content below the absolut position element..

Comment: can you please tell how big the text will be on the image??.. is it static??